# printf() format specifier for int64_t and uint64_t in 32-bit ANSI C

Tags: c

I'm writing some 32-bit ANSI C, compiling with `gcc`, in which I need to print some 64-bit signed and unsigned integers. The problem is that in `gcc` 32-bit C, `int64_t` and `uint64_t` get converted to long long int and unsigned long long int respectively, with format specifier `%lld` and `%llu`, which are not supported by ANSI C. Using the format specifier macros provided in `inttypes.h` don't help either, since those get converted to `%lld` and `%llu`.

The following code fails to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    uint64_t some_int = 123456789;
    printf("Your int is: %"PRId64"\n", some_int);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc main.c -ansi -Og -g -m32 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic`

Error message is:

```
error: ISO C90 does not support the ‘ll’ gnu_printf length modifier [-Werror=format=]
```

So, my question is: What format specifier should I use to print double-length integers in 32-bit ANSI C?

Comment: What is known as [ANSI C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) is actually the precursor to the ISO standardization of C. It is also *very old* and unless you have an equally old compiler you should at least attempt to use [the C99 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). Even Microsoft Visual C compiler support most of C99 these days.

Comment: "_it fails..._" - what errors do you see?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm well aware. This is actually code from a personal project that was C99 compliant, and that I'm trying to make ANSI C compliant. If it turns out to not be reasonably possible I'll just go back to C99.

Comment: Can't remember exactly but was `uint64_t` defined in ANSI C? Probably not...

Comment: @tmaxthomas: I get no compiler error for your code with this command line.

Comment: @Attie Error message added to question.

Comment: Well since `uint64_t` was introduced in the C99 standard, there's really no portable way to handle 64-bit integers in older compilers. Why do you want to port it to an older standard? Considering that all three of the big compilers (GCC, Clang and MSVC) now support C99 (and all or most of C11 even) since long back, I don't really see a reason for it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The only reason I want to port it is to see if I can. The answer appears to be a resounding "no", so I guess I'll just switch back to C99. Consider this question answered.

Comment: The term "ANSI C" is commonly used to refer to the language defined by the 1989 ANSI C standard, which is identical to the language defined by the 1990 ISO C standard (which was then adopted by ANSI). The 1999 and 2011 editions of the C standard were published by ISO and then officially adopted by ANSI. So ANSI, the organization, recognizes ISO C11 as the current C standard. Since "ANSI C" is ambiguous, I suggest you refer to the year of a standard. By "ANSI C", I suspect you mean C90 (which can also be called C89).

Comment: Use this instead: `gcc -std=c99 main.c -Og -g -m32 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic`. That is, drop the `-ansi` and instead use `-std=c99` to use the C99 standard, which is more recent. `-ansi` will instead an older standard (C90), that you really shouldn't use anymore.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "32-bit C", and why do you want it? The `-m32` option affects which architecture it generates code for, but C itself doesn't have any defined "bitness".

Comment: @NikosC.: Why do you recommend `-std=c99` rather than `-std=c11`?

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't, actually. But now it's too late to edit the comment :-| So yeah. If you don't have a reason to prefer C99 (like wanting better compatibility with Microsoft's C compiler, which AFAIK doesn't support C11?), then just use C11.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "ANSI C" commonly refers to the language defined by the 1989 ISO C standard. The 1990 ISO C standard describes exactly the same language (it adds some ISO-mandated sections). ANSI officially dropped its own 1989 standard and adopted the ISO standard -- and has also adopted the 1999 and 2011 editions of the ISO C standard. So the C standard defined by ANSI is the 2011 ISO C standard.

Because of this ambiguity, I suggest avoiding the phrase "ANSI C" and referring to the year in which the standard was published by ISO: C90, C99, or C11.

> **What format specifier should I use to print double-length integers in 32-bit ANSI C?**

There is none.

C90 did not support the  and  header or the type `long long`. It did not require support for any 64-bit integer type (`long` *may* be 64 bits, but is commonly 32). Because the types didn't exist, `printf` provided no format specifiers for them.

In principle, you could use a C90 implementation that supports 64-bit `long` (sacrificing portability), or you could implement your own 64-bit type using an array of narrower integers, providing operations as functions.

If you could update your question to explain exactly **why** you want to restrict yourself to a 29-year-old version of the C standard, it might be possible to give a more useful answer. I'd tell you simply to use an implementation that support C99 or C11, but you've indicated that's not a solution (without explaining why).

Comment: Replacing `-ansi` with `-std=c99` (or `-std=c11` to use the C11 standard) would fix this. I suspect that the `-ansi` switch is misleading people here, since it kind of looks like a good way to enable "standard C" mode in GCC. The name of that switch is really unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure you can use a 64 bit integer with a C89 compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
typedef unsigned long uint64_t;

int main() {
    uint64_t some_int = 123456789;
    assert(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(long) >= 64);
    printf("Your int is: %lu\n", some_int);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't ensure that you have 64-bit integers, it simply fails to compile if your compiler doesn't provide them.

Comment: Which can be useful if that's what you need, but it's not what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Actually (and I'm sure Keith knows this) it aborts at *run-time* (I felt that the compile-time "assert" using a negative array size was a bit over the top here) if `long` is smaller than 64 bits. But if it runs, you are guaranteed that you have 64-bit integers. Unless you use an aftermarket multiple-precision package, the *only* way you get 64 bits in C89 is if the vendor provides them.

Comment: You're right, it aborts at compile time, not at run time. (C89/C90 didn't have `#error`). I still don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson, C89 lacking `#error` is news to my copy of draft N843, and K&R2. In any case, within the constraints of C89, if `long` is at least 64 bits then this is the way to print such a value.

Comment: You're right, C89/C90 does have `#error`. (I believe C99 added the requirement that `#error` causes translation to fail; C89/C90 merely requires a diagnostic. I suspect most or all C89/C90 compilers did treat it as a fatal error, though.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, once you started commenting on *this* answer my opinion of your C knowledge took a nosedive. It would really help if you actually read the standard (or a draft thereof) in question before commenting on it. Way back in 1989 section 4 Conformance said "[#4] The implementation shall not successfully translate a preprocessing translation unit containing a #error preprocessing directive unless it is part of a group skipped by conditional inclusion." So, for the third time here: you're demonstrably wrong. SMH.

Comment: Can you cite the exact name of the document you're quoting? The 1989 ANSI C standard did not have a "Conformance" section (I have a plain-text draft, not the actual standard). In the 1990 ISO C standard, section 4 is titled "Compliance", not "Conformance", and it does not include the wording you cite (my copy is `ansi+iso+9899-1990+(r1997).pdf`). That wording does appear in the C99 standard. Images: https://imgur.com/a/CjWXI

Comment: JTC1/SC22/WG14 N843 (linked-to from http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/index.html as "N843, the official committee document")

Comment: and I can climb down off my own high horse: N843 is pre-C99, so you may well be correct regarding the absence of a requirement to terminate compilation upon encountering `#error`. But plenty of compilers I encountered already implemented this, even back in '89.